# strlen: Address out of bounds leading to segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, strlen

I'm trying to do a couple simple implementations of string_reverse in C. However, I get the following error when I debug in gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005ca in string_reverse1 (string=0x68 <Address 0x68 out of bounds>)
28          length = strlen(*string);
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.15-58.fc17.x86_64
```

Here's my code for the error I'm getting (I commented on the line where the error comes from):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *char1 = "hello";
    char *char2 = "hi";
    char *char3 = "this is a really long string!";

    string_reverse1(*char1);
    string_reverse1(*char2);
    string_reverse1(*char3);
    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", char1, char2, char3);

    return 0;
}

//Assuming method's purpose is to reverse the passed string
//and set the original string equal to the reversed one
void string_reverse1(char *string) 
{
    //Calculate length once so it isn't recalculated at
    //every iteration of the for loop
    int length;
    char *reversed;
    int i;
    int reversed_counter;
    length = strlen(*string); //ERROR
    reversed_counter = 0;
    for(i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed[reversed_counter] = string[i];
        reversed_counter++;
    }
    //Can't forget to add the terminating null character!
    reversed[length] = '\0';
    string = reversed;
}
```

I know that strlen returns the length of a passed string by advancing through the string until it lands on \0, the null byte. So I'm wondering if perhaps the string passed is somehow not null-terminated? I don't think I declared the strings incorrectly in main though.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you call `string_reverse1`:

```
string_reverse1(*char1);
```

The `*` before `char1` dereferences `char1` returning the value of the first character of the string. If you want to pass the `*char` you should just omit the `*`. This is because the type of `char1` is already `char *`. There's no need to change it.

When you dereference `char1` you're sending the actual ascii value of the first character, 'h'. Then `strlen` is attempting to access the memory at address 'h' and segfaulting because that's just some arbitrary memory location.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That makes sense. I also took out the * when I passed string to strlen and now it's working with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of...

```
string_reverse1(*char1);
```

...do this:

```
string_reverse1(char1);
```

Your string definitions are already pointers, so that's what you need to pass in.  Dereferencing them gives a value that is not at all a memory address.

Answer (score 0):

According to your declaration void string_reverse1(char *string),

```
  length = strlen(*string); //ERROR
```

should be changed to

```
   length = strlen(string);
```

The main program should call the function as

```
string_reverse1(char1);
string_reverse1(char2);
string_reverse1(char3);
```

Then there is an error at

reversed[reversed_counter] = string[i];

because you haven't allocated space for your characters (Segmentation Fault usually results from accessing unallocated memory.

One way to fix this is using

```
char* reversed = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));
```

You will still have a problem with this code, because

```
string = reversed;
```

does not actually change the contents of "string". You can change the way the function works, to solve this problem. A better way is to change the characters in "string" itself, instead of using another array.